# SV assertion based on event trigger

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

Assume SV interface contains a concurrent assertion property. 
Is it possible to enable this assertion only when an event is triggered? I tried writing property inside a task in interface file, but I ended up with error: near *"property": syntax error, unexpected property.*

```
Interface intf;

   task e1();
        -> e1; 
   endtask

   wait(e1.triggered); // something like this, where property waits for trigger 
   property prop1;
     @(posedge clk) a ##1 b;
   endproperty

endinterface
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to consider that properties are best written synchronously and are evaluated on every clock cycle. You property says that one cycle after every clock cycle where `a` occurs `b` occurs. I guess what you're after is something like:

> if `e1` occurs, then a should be true (on the next rising edge of
>   `clk`?) and then b should be true on the rising edge of `clk` after
>   that

So, one way of doing that would be to create an always block that generates a pulse one clock wide should `e1` occur, eg:

```
always begin
  @(e1);
  @(posedge clk) e = 1'b1;
  @(posedge clk) e = 1'b0;
end

property prop1;
 @(posedge clk) e |-> a ##1 b;
endproperty
```

or some variation of that. I feel like I should be worried about races, however.